# How to unset $GODEBUG

Tags: go

I've been using [Dave Cheney's `gcvis` tool](https://github.com/davecheney/gcvis) to troubleshoot a memory leak. All went well, problem solved.

However, I have no idea how, but I cannot for the life of me stop the garbage collector output from flooding my logs, making development very difficult.

According to [the `runtime`-package manual](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/):

> Setting gctrace to any value > 0 also causes the garbage collector
>   to emit a summary when memory is released back to the system.

This, however, has no effect.

How can I remove the output?

---

I have tried the following:

**Exporting to empty value**

```
$ export GODEBUG=
$ go run main.go
```

**Unsetting**

```
$ unset GODEBUG
$ go run main.go
```

**Setting to zero** *(also tried w / o quotation marks, just for completion)*

```
$ export GODEBUG="gctrace=0"
$ go run main.go
```

Regardless, I get this output every time (package names redacted):

```
# my-package-0
gc 1 @0.006s 10%: 0.025+3.4+0.11 ms clock, 0.20+1.7/5.9/1.7+0.94 ms cpu, 4->4->3 MB, 5 MB goal, 8 P
gc 2 @0.019s 7%: 0.005+1.0+0.086 ms clock, 0.047+0.67/1.8/2.8+0.69 ms cpu, 5->5->4 MB, 6 MB goal, 8 P
gc 3 @0.030s 6%: 0.006+2.8+0.091 ms clock, 0.053+0.10/4.8/4.2+0.73 ms cpu, 7->8->6 MB, 8 MB goal, 8 P
gc 4 @0.050s 6%: 0.030+4.2+0.096 ms clock, 0.24+1.0/7.3/3.7+0.76 ms cpu, 13->14->8 MB, 14 MB goal, 8 P
# my-package-1
gc 1 @0.007s 5%: 0.010+2.6+0.15 ms clock, 0.086+0.19/3.4/2.6+1.2 ms cpu, 4->4->2 MB, 5 MB goal, 8 P
gc 2 @0.015s 6%: 0.007+2.5+0.11 ms clock, 0.060+0.63/3.4/2.4+0.91 ms cpu, 5->5->4 MB, 6 MB goal, 8 P
gc 3 @0.028s 6%: 0.010+3.0+0.53 ms clock, 0.084+0.23/2.7/2.4+4.2 ms cpu, 8->9->5 MB, 9 MB goal, 8 P
# my-package-3
gc 1 @0.009s 15%: 0.012+4.5+1.7 ms clock, 0.10+0.62/4.5/0.77+13 ms cpu, 4->4->2 MB, 5 MB goal, 8 P
gc 2 @0.030s 9%: 0.006+2.8+0.10 ms clock, 0.050+0.63/3.7/2.9+0.85 ms cpu, 5->5->4 MB, 6 MB goal, 8 P
gc 3 @0.043s 11%: 0.53+3.9+0.084 ms clock, 4.3+7.0/7.8/5.2+0.67 ms cpu, 9->10->7 MB, 10 MB goal, 8 P
gc 4 @0.062s 10%: 0.027+3.6+0.12 ms clock, 0.21+5.2/6.3/5.0+1.0 ms cpu, 12->13->8 MB, 14 MB goal, 8 P
# my-package-4
[...]
```

---

On request in comments, here is the output from `$ go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/dimholt/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/dimholt/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/fx/p9gpbcnd5_jdgqyp6z1w9tqr0000gn/T/go-build333219542=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

And my `main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/redacted/config"
    "github.com/redacted/db"
)

func main() {
    conf := config.GetConfig()

    // Connect database.
    db.Connect()
    defer db.Close()

    // Register all HTTP routes.
    registerRoutes()

    port := fmt.Sprintf(":%v", conf.Port)
    log.Printf("documents: listening on port %v", port[1:])
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(port, nil))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else run into this problem, this worked for me.

```sh
go clean -cache
```

Answer (score 1):

Something else is wrong.

Running `GODEBUG= go run main.go` should definitely run your `main.go` without `GODEBUG` on. Feel free to `os.Getenv` at the start of `main.go` to check `GODEBUG` - it should be off.

Can you minimize your `main.go` and show it? You could be setting the debug flags somehow from inside the code.

Try running `go env` and see what's set

Comment: Hey Eli! Thanks for your reply. I can't comment that output since it's too long, but I'll update my original post with the information you requested.

Comment: Also, added this to `main.go`:

```
 gdbg := os.Getenv("GODEBUG")
 log.Printf("GODEBUG: %v", gdbg)
```

Output is:

```
# my-package
[...]
gc 8 @1.302s 12%: 0.021+19+0.11 ms clock, 0.17+1.1/35/32+0.89 ms cpu, 93->101->54 MB, 102 MB goal, 8 P
gc 9 @1.407s 11%: 0.010+10+0.066 ms clock, 0.083+2.7/19/42+0.53 ms cpu, 100->101->53 MB, 109 MB goal, 8 P
[...]
2019/05/03 16:42:40 GODEBUG:
```

Comment: @HelgeTalvikSöderström: it doesn't seem like your code is setting these env vars. What about the dependency? `config` package, is it setting it?

Comment: No... nothing in my code set is. All I did was download the gcvis-package, ran `$ export GODEBUG=gctrace=1` and then troubleshot my code. When I was done I kept working. It wasn't even this system that I was troubleshooting the memory leak in. I'll check if `gcvis` does it somehow...

Comment: @HelgeTalvikSöderström: something is weird in your setup. Build you program again in a separate shell where GODEBUG wasn't set. Verify first that it's not set, then run the program. It shouldn't print these.